# Meteorjs as a desktop app

Tags: meteor

I'm building an app for a friend of mine, very easy app, it should be a menu manager for a restaurant.

I'm building the app using meteorjs and I'm obtaining the desktop app using: https://github.com/wojtkowiak/meteor-desktop

Now my problem is database-related. Infact when I move the desktop app to another computer everything seems to work but the database doesn't.

Is there a way I can use any database option that can works everywhere?

Comment: why don't you use mlab for database ?

Comment: because my friend can't access internet from the restaurant

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest two options based on your friend's networking situation:

1) If all the computers at the restaurant are networked together, but just don't have access to the outside internet, then you can setup a mongo server on one of the local computers, and have all computers connect to that. This has the advantage that you only have to maintain one database (e.g. when the menu changes).

2) If the computers are not networked at all, then you'll need to run a local mongo for each machine. The problem here is populating the database for multiple machines. Assuming that the data is fairly static (i.e. the menu data only changes once in a while), and none of the machines will be doing any updates, you can insert the data into a master mongoDB, then dump the data and reload it into each machine. As long as the data is static, this can be workable. But each time you update the data, you'll need to manually clear and re-import the fresh data on each computer.

Comment: My question was kinda more technich. I already know he will use only a computer so no problems on the strategy. But when i pack the app with the tool in the link only the client-side gets packed.
I may have found a solution with another tool called "electrify" which packs also the server-side.